# Target is not instantiable. Laravel 5 - App binding service provider

Tags: php, laravel-5

**I'm getting this error:**

```
BindingResolutionException in compiled.php line 1029:

Target [App\Models\Contracts\Repositories\IUserRepository] is not instantiable.
```

**My code is as follows:**

Interface:

```
namespace App\Models\Contracts\Repositories;

use App\Models\Objects\DTO\User;

interface IUserRepository
{
    function Create( User $user );
}
```

Concrete:

```
namespace App\Models\Concrete\Eloquent;

use App\Models\Contracts\Repositories\IUserRepository;
use App\Models\Objects\DTO\User;

class EqUserRepository implements IUserRepository
{
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    public function Create( User $user )
    {
        return User::create( [
                    'first_name' => $user->first_name,
                    'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                    'username' => $user->username,
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'password' => bcrypt( $user->password ),
                ] );
    }

}
```

Service Provider:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * This service provider is a great spot to register your various container
     * bindings with the application. As you can see, we are registering our
     * "Registrar" implementation here. You can add your own bindings too!
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

            $this->app->bind(
                    'App\Models\Contracts\Repositories\IUserRepository', 
                    'App\Models\Concrete\Eloquent\EqUserRepository'
            );
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

use App\Models\Contracts\Repositories\IUserRepository;
use App\Models\Objects\DTO\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $auth;
    private $userRepository;

    public function __Construct(  
            Guard $auth, 
            IUserRepository $userRepo )
    {
    ...
```

Folder structure

[image]

I have also seen that I may need to declare the namespaces in my composer.json, So i have tried the following as well as just the above:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "App\\Models\\Concrete\\Eloquent\\": "app/Models/Concrete/Eloquent/",
            "App\\Models\\Contracts\\Repositories\\": "app/Models/Contracts/Repositories/",
            "App\\Models\\Objects\\DTO\\": "app/Models/Objects/DTO/"
        }
    },
```

and then ran `composer dump-autoload`

**Any ideas what I am forgetting to do?**

Comment: I've moved the concrete repository to the services folder and given it that namespace. Still the same error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I noticed the compiled.php was not being updated.

Run this function in cmd line on the root folder of your project:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Comment: This was very helpfull

Comment: I had to run a few other commands to clear the cache and optimize also. `php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan clear-compiled`
`php artisan optimize`
`php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 7):

If you also run in below error :

> BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 749: Target
>   [App\Contracts\TestContract] is not instantiable.

Clear your config cache with :

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-solve-target-apprepositoriesnewsreposi

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was, I added protected keyword in controller __construct method

Before

```
protected function __construct()
```

After

```
public function __construct()
```

Because I am using polices resource and  I added $this->authorizeResource(Task::class); in my construct method, to apply it on all methods.

Answer (score -1):

I had same error solved by adding repository in app/providers/AppServiceProvider in register method like the below.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

public function register()
    {
        $this->app->register(RepositoryServiceProvider::class); // here
    }
}
```