# How can I solve Target [App\Repositories\NewsRepository] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Member\NewsController].?

Tags: laravel, repository, laravel-5.4

My controller like this :

```
...
use App\Repositories\NewsRepository;
class NewsController extends Controller
{
    protected $repository;
    public function __construct(NewsRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
    public function store(NewsCreateRequest $request)
    {
        ...
        $news = $this->repository->create($input);
        ...
    }
}
```

My interface like this :

```
namespace App\Repositories;
use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\RepositoryInterface;
interface NewsRepository extends RepositoryInterface
{
    //
}
```

My class like this :

```
...
use App\Repositories\NewsRepository;
class NewsRepositoryEloquent extends BaseRepository implements NewsRepository
{
    public function model()
    {
        return News::class;
    }
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->pushCriteria(app(RequestCriteria::class));
    }
}
```

My repository service provider like this :

```
...
class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    ...
    public function register()
    {
        ...
        $this->app->bind(\App\Repositories\NewsRepository::class, \App\Repositories\NewsRepositoryEloquent::class);
    }
}
```

If the method store on the controller executed, there exist error :

> (1/1) BindingResolutionException Target
>   [App\Repositories\NewsRepository] is not instantiable while building
>   [App\Http\Controllers\Member\NewsRepository].

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Have you added the `RepositoryServiceProvider` to the providers array in `config/app.php` ?

Comment: @Norris Oduro, Yes, I add it. Like this : `Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class`

Comment: can you post your  `RepositoryInterface` here

Comment: @Norris Oduro, https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository/blob/master/src/Prettus/Repository/Contracts/RepositoryInterface.php

Comment: lets chat about it https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/153230/resolving-error

Answer (score 0):

You have to add constructor to your repository and call parent constructor for setup model like this:

```
public function __construct(Permission $model)
{
    parent::__construct($model);
}
```